# Singleton class for global access to GoogleCredentials in App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

In my App Engine project, I want to have a valid access token to Cloud Storage globally available for the application instance throughtout the life cycle. This is how I was thinking of doing it:

```
public class GoogleCredentialsHolder
{
    private static GoogleCredentialsHolder instance = null;
    private GoogleCredential credentials;

    public static synchronized GoogleCredentialsHolder getInstance() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException
    {
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new GoogleCredentialsHolder();
        return instance;
    }

    private GoogleCredentialsHolder() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException
    {
        credentials = getGoogleCredential();
        credentials.refreshToken();
    }

    private GoogleCredential getGoogleCredential() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException
    {
        JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId(Constants.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(Constants.CLOUD_STORAGE_KEY))
            .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write"))
            .build();
        return credential;
    }

    public String getAccessToken() throws IOException
    {
        if(Calendar.getInstance().after(credentials.getExpirationTimeMilliseconds()))
            credentials.refreshToken();

        return credentials.getAccessToken();
    }
}
```

Will this work, or could this approach cause any problems?

Comment: You should post these kind of questions here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: André, as User404 pointed out, it is not really the proper place to post this kind of question. Stack is meant for questions where stuff doesn't work, not posting your code and asking if there is a better way. Looking into it, I think that it should work fine. But in any case, you should be able to try it by deploying your code, no?

Comment: Didn't know about codereview.stackexchange.com, will post there next time I have this type of question. The code seemingly works fine, I just wasn't sure about the performance or issues by using this type of singleton pattern on App Engine with potential high traffic. I'll figure it out :)

Comment: Have you figured it out? Does this approach of ever-valid service account credential object work ok for long periods (multiple token refreshes) and high concurrency environment?

Comment: It worked in my case, but only tested on low concurrency environment